# Does MySql automatically lock rows or do I need to add "lock in share mode"?

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

We're beginners and our java  software gets queries from the database using select * etc.

My question is do we need to add lock in share mode and "FOR UPDATE" to enforce the locks, or are table and row locks automatic?

We have one table where we want to enforce concurrency, could I just add LOCK TABLE to the table i need to lock, update then values, then unlock it?

Comment: Want do you mean by you need to "enforce concurrency"? Do you mean you need to enforce transactional consistency across a number of related queries? What database engine are you using, as there can be significant differences between engines with regards to how they handle transactions, table and row level locking, etc.?

Comment: @mikeBrant, yes, i need to enforce transactional consistency across related queries. There is one table in particular that may be written to simultaneously. I believe the engine we are using is Innodb.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that based on your answers to my comments, you really shouldn't have to worry about manually handling table locks.  InnoDB supports row-level locking and with autocommit enabled (as it is by default) all individual queries are actually handled in a transactional manner.

Now if you have multiple SQL queries that need to be handled as a single transaction (i.e. update one table, then update another table - either both succeed or both get rolled back) then you would need to specifically start a transaction and either commit it or roll it back after the provisional queries have been executed.

You can also use `SET TRANSACTION` statement if you need to change the transaction isolation level (it is `REPEATABLE READ1 by default).

For more information check out the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-transaction-model.html)