# Is this SQL concurrency safe?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to increment a field in a table:

```
UID | AMOUNT
5   | 100
```

The long way to do this, is:

```
select amount from table where uid = 5

update table set amount = 101 where uid = 5
```

However, concurrency issues can arise. Before update is executed, another process could have updated the field.

Instead of this, would the following not solve my problem:

```
update table set amount = amount + 1 where uid = 5
```

Would MySQL lock the field by itself and insure I don't create a concurrency side effect?

Comment: Wouldnt the second method only work when you want to increase the value by 1 automatically??? The first approach sets the variable to a specified value i.e. 101 so no matter how many times the query is ran....the same output will occur in concurrency as well...

Comment: My point is, I want to alter the value, whether up or down or whatever, in one swift motion. I am wondering if MySQL does the locking needed or would I need to still do locking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this update, select combination query thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044768/is-this-update-select-combination-query-thread-safe)

Answer (score 3):

May be this link will help you [Does MySql automatically lock rows or do I need to add "lock in share mode"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13595788/14280980)
You can also consider creating a transaction as given below.

```sql
begin;
select amount from table where uid = 5 for update;
update table set amount = 101 where uid = 5;
commit;
```

The `for update` statement will lock that row and prevent reading the row by another transactions.

Comment: I know this would work. I want to know if my code does the same but is a faster way of doing the above.